# Rspec rails api controller index test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

I'm trying to test an api controller action with rspec, but since i am quite new to rspec i can't make it work.
I have the following index action: render json: @website.jobs

I have to find all associated jobs to a website by name. Here is my spec:

```
let(:endpoint) { FactoryGirl.create(:website) }
let(:job) { FactoryGirl.create(:job) }

subject do
  get :index, params: { format: :json, 
                       name: endpoint.name }
end

expect(subject.body).to include(:job)
```

Am i doing something wrong, or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check the object directly with the `JSON` response. You can do something like this:

```
it "response with JSON body containing expected jobs" do
  hash_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
  expect(hash_body).first.to match({
    id: job.id,
    title: job.title
  })
end
```

You need to change the attributes according to your `Job` model.

A good tutorial for testing JSON using Rspec: [Pure RSpec JSON API testing](http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/30-native-rspec-json-api-testing)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helped me if not OP! +1 for the tutorial

Comment: Not sure if i am explaining it, or understanding wrong. Don't i need to assign  a job to the website first ? So i can make a request for that website and the output should be the assigned job. Then all that outputted to a json format.

Comment: So you can do that like this: `FactoryGirl.create(:job, website: website)` and you need to define the `website` attribute in the factory